# make setTimeout as generic function and exec timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 functions, assume they are function a, b and c. All of them require a delay to start in different scope.

I can do in different places and event like this

```
setTimeout(function()a()},100);
setTimeout(function()b()},100);
setTimeout(function()c()},100);
```

but how can I make it cleaner?

Comment: `setTimeout(function()a();b();c();},100);`

Comment: @Mahi lol nope man. I need to trigger them in different event. What I want is to make the setTimeout function a generic function.

Comment: what do you mean by generic here, not cleat what are you asking for

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what ES6 Promises were made for.

```
function a() { console.log('a') }
function b() { console.log('b') }
function c() { console.log('c') }

function foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    });
}

foo()
    .then(a)
    .then(b)
    .then(c)
```

I understand this example is a little vague. But if you understand promises you can adapt it pretty well to your problem (and if you are not familiar with promises you can master Promises in a matter of hours).

You could also use Observables from Rjrx. The "fromInterval" operator is what you are looking for. Observables might be part of ES7.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this approach.**

```js
function a() {
  console.log("function a");
}
function b() {
  console.log("function b");
}
function c() {
  console.log("function c");
}

function callFunction(ref) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    ref();
  },5000);
}

callFunction(a);
callFunction(b);
callFunction(c);

/* These are anonymous function. These will never wait for each other ro execute.*/
setTimeout(function(){a();},5000); 
setTimeout(function(){b();},5000); 
setTimeout(function(){c();},5000);
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat , if you don't know how it is working, please don't down vote. Now check, it will wait for 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you even understand what this code does `setTimeout(function()a()},100);
setTimeout(function()b()},100);
setTimeout(function()c()},100);`? and what is the requirement? Refer [Kamil Latosinski](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5515745/kamil-latosinski)'s answer

Comment: I just increased the time , nothing else. Now you get to know what i was doing. Don't just rush and down vote. see the time out duration, it'll never get noticed.

Comment: Are you not getting it bro? The functions should execute like this way `a();` then `wait for 100ms` then `b();` and `wait for 100ms` What your code does is this=> IT WAITS FOR `100ms` and executes `a(); b(); c();` without any timeout

Comment: He just want a timeout before calling the function. See his example , same thing is happening and he said he is able to achieve it, but he want a clearer code . That's all @AniketSahrawat

Answer (score 1):

Before we start, as its common misconception, you must know that `setTimeout` time passed doesn't mean it will be executed exactly after 100ms. It can be longer (just not earlier). You should definitly watch a great talk by Philip Roberts - [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

**Edit** - as my answer covers `setTimeout-way` I think the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40800051/5515745) given by @Adam Kettani is what you need, as with promises you can be sure the code will be executed in the right time and order, and it is also more clean what is going on.

Okay, let's get down to business. You can put them in array and then use a `forEach

```js
const functions = [
    function (){
        console.log('a');
    },
    function (){
        console.log('b');
    },
    function (){
        console.log('c');
    },
];

functions.forEach(fn => setTimeout(fn, 1000));
```

Keep in mind that they all will be set with timeout 1000ms, so they will most likely execute at the same time. If you want to have a delay in-between too just modify `forEach`:

```js
const functions = [
    function (){
        console.log('a');
    },
    function (){
        console.log('b');
    },
    function (){
        console.log('c');
    },
];

functions.forEach((fn, index) => setTimeout(fn, index * 2000));
```

To make this generic you can extract this line of code to a function:

```js
const functions = [
    function (){
        console.log('a');
    },
    function (){
        console.log('b');
    },
    function (){
        console.log('c');
    },
];

function _setTimeout (fn, delay) {
    // setTimeout returns a value that allows you to
    // cancel timeout, so it would be great if our function
    // has this feature of converting array of functions
    // to array of timeout ids
    return fn.reduce((timeoutIds, fn, index) => {
        return [...timeoutIds, setTimeout(fn, index * delay)];
    }, []);
}

const timeouts = _setTimeout(functions, 2000);
console.log(timeouts);

clearTimeout(timeouts[2]);
console.log('C shall not pass!');
```

Comment: What you mean there is no gap between the execution? I have presented two versions that cover both use cases.